# Difference among 'thrown out', 'ousted' and 'expelled'

Tags: vocabulary

I'm little confused with these three words. What would be the best?

Stallone was **thrown out/ousted/expelled** from fourteen different schools in eleven years.

Comment: Thrown out in this context would be an informal version of expelled - but ousted is usually reserved for some position of authority, which required junior members or a public vote to remove you from. [edit - but it would be thrown out *of*, not from]

Comment: A quick note - if you use thrown out above, it needs 'of' - Stallone was thrown out OF fourteen different...

Comment: The usual formal term in the UK (at least in the state school system) "excluded", or "suspended" for if the exclusion is temporary. "Expelled" sounds a bit old-fashioned, or would be used by a UK "public school" (= US "private school") Ref: https://www.gov.uk/school-discipline-exclusions/exclusions. "Ousted" means "removed from a position of authority". The school governors might oust the head teacher for some misdemeanour, but exclude or expel a student.

Answer (score 4):

If you're specifically talking about **school**, the US term is always expelled, assuming it was the school doing the expulsion.

As you can see in this dictionary definition, the first definition of "[expel](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/expel)" is used to directly relate to schools:

> *expel* - to officially force someone to leave a school or organization

"[Ousted](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/oust)" is more commonly used to refer to dictators/rulers who were removed from power. I've personally never heard someone use it to refer to a person kicked out of school.

> *oust* - to force someone out of a position of power, especially so that you can take their place

"Thrown out" could work but I'd actually argue that "kicked out" is more commonly used in relation to a bad student getting expelled from a school. Here's an example from a magazine article about school expulsions:

> **Life After Getting Expelled: What Really Happens When Students Are Kicked out of School** - Hilary George-Parkin TeenVogue
>   Cutting class, texting in homeroom, talking back to teachers: Sometimes it seems like there are a million different ways to get in trouble in high school. But what happens when a big mistake—or even a bunch of smaller ones—leads to something as extreme as suspension or expulsion? Are you totally out of luck? Or is it possible to get back on track after getting kicked out?

Also, as others have noted in comments, if you use "kicked out" or "thrown out", you need to use "of" not "from".

> *He was kicked out **of** fourteen different schools in eleven years.*

Comment: That's a valuable input @Catija. Thank you for the effort. I feel I should go with 'expelled'